# A union is connected, connected functions

Tags: general-topology

If A and B are connected subsets of a topological space X and $\bar{A}\cap B \neq \emptyset$, then $A\cup B$ is connected.

The picture is my teachers solution. I gave up a little to understand solution 1 (I looked at a question here and compared the solutions but still didnt get it) so I decided to at least understand solution 2. The thing I dont understand is the main steps in the proof, she shows that the restictions are connected, that the function is equal to zero (constant) but I dont get how this makes sense.[image: teachers solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one solution here (step 1 is just preparatory stuff). I'll attempt to add details, hopefully enough that you can grok it, along with some re-ordering to make things clearer.

---

We need to show that there is no combination of open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $A \cup B$ such that $A \cup B = U \cup V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Firstly, note that $A \cup B$ not being connected is equivalent to there being a non-constant continuous map $f: A\cup B \to \{0,1\}$. We're going to assume that such an $f$ exists, and try to derive a contradiction.

What we know to start with is that $\bar{A} \cap B$ is non-empty, so we know that there is something in it: let $p$ be one such point. Without loss of generality, assume $f(p) = 0$ (else compose $f$ with the map swapping $1$ and $0$).

Now, since $B$ is connected, $f|_B$ must be constant, and since $f(p) = 0$, we must have $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in B$.

And $f^{-1}(0)$ is a pre-image of an open set under a continuous map, so is open, and contains $p$, so is an open neighbourhood of $p$. B

ut since $p \in \bar{A}$, by definition of the closure, $f^{-1}(0)$ must intersect $A$, so there is some point $a \in A$ with $f(a) = 0$.

But $A$ is connected, so $f|_A$ is constant, so $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in B$.

Combining this with the result three lines up, we have that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A \cup B$, contradicting our assumption that $f$ is non-constant.

Thus, $A \cup B$ must be connected.

Comment: Thank you so much, so much clearer!

Comment: I dont really get why we need to say that we want to prove that there are no such sets U and V? Is it just not like saying that $A \cap B= \emptyset$?

Comment: Sure, you could word it that way (minus the typo). "For all open $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup B = X$, we do not have $A \cap B =\emptyset$" is equivalent to $There do not exist open $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup B = X$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. I don't see a particular reason to prefer the former over the latter.